How do I set different strata order, drop label edges, and fix overlapping labels in r package ggalluvial?
I am trying to customize some ggalluvial plots in r and there are three aspects that I find difficult to set. I have inserted a dummy table for explanation below:

I would like to reorder the plot so that bio drug name (middle column) is ordered by size of the strata, e.g., baricitinib should be at the top. I found this related case, but I was not able to figure out how to do it based on the explanation: https://corybrunson.github.io/ggalluvial/articles/order-rectangles.html

As you can see, some labels are overlapping, which is not optimal. As far as I understand, ggalluvial does not allow inserting space between the strata so that the labels are more visible ("No gaps are inserted between the strata, so the total height of the plot reflects the cumulative quantity of the observations." https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalluvial/vignettes/ggalluvial.html). I wonder if there is another work-around for making sure labels don't overlap or if I should use ggsankey instead of ggalluvial.

Each of the category labels in each strata are boxed with a black line around them. I am trying to remove it but could not figure out how. Examples here do not put the labels in boxes, and yet I can't figure out which code allows that. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalluvial/vignettes/ggalluvial.html


# dummy dataset
btsd <- c("anticd20", "anticd20", "coi", "coi", "coi", "jaki", "jaki", "coi")
mult_conc2 <- c("mtx", "mtx", "none", "mtx", "multi", "mtx", "none", "multi")
cond_psoriasis <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
bio_drug_name <- c("rituximab", "anakinra", "rituximab", "baricitinib", "etanercept", "etanercept", "ustekinumab", "guselkumab")
count <- c(5, 5, 4, 500, 3, 2, 2, 7)
allu4 <- data.frame(btsd, mult_conc2, cond_psoriasis, bio_drug_name, count)
rm("bio_drug_name", "btsd", "cond_psoriasis", "count", "mult_conc2")
cols <- c("btsd", "bio_drug_name", "mult_conc2", "cond_psoriasis")
allu4 <- allu4 %>% mutate_at(cols, factor)
rm(cols)

# plot
ggplot(as.data.frame(allu4),
       aes(y = count, axis1 = btsd, axis2 = bio_drug_name, axis3 = mult_conc2)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = bio_drug_name), width = 1/12) +
  geom_stratum(alpha = 1, width = 1/5, fill = "#ffffff", color = "black") +
  geom_label(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum)), size = 3) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("drug class", "bio drug name", "concomittant"), expand = c(0.1, 
  0.1)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set1") +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  #coord_flip() +
  ggtitle("b-tsDMARD, concommitant treatment and condition") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")


To get the desired order for the bio drugs you can use reorder. For the overlapping labels you could try with ggrepel::geom_label_repel and the outline around the labels can be removed by setting label.size = 0:
library(ggalluvial)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

allu4 <- allu4 |> mutate(
  bio_drug_name = reorder(bio_drug_name, -count, FUN = sum)
)

ggplot(
  allu4,
  aes(y = count, axis1 = btsd, axis2 = bio_drug_name, axis3 = mult_conc2)
) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = bio_drug_name), width = 1 / 12) +
  geom_stratum(alpha = 1, width = 1 / 5, fill = "#ffffff", color = "black") +
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(
    stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum)), size = 3,
    direction = "y",
    nudge_x = .25,
    label.size = 0
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(
    limits = c("drug class", "bio drug name", "concomittant"),
    expand = c(0.1, 0.1)
  ) +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set1") +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  # coord_flip() +
  ggtitle("b-tsDMARD, concommitant treatment and condition") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")



Thank you very much, @stefan, this is super useful! I did not know the ggrepel package and I definitely use that in future figures.
